# How to extract a string from a column that contains short comments?

Tags: r, regex, string

I am trying to come up with a code that will allow me to re-categorize a column in a data set that contains short comments from  survey by doing the following:

1. If the comment is empty/NA/blank then assign "NO_COMMENT"
2. If the short comment has the word "outdated" (lowercase, caps or in any combination) then assign "OUTDATED"
3. Any other comment will be left as it is

For example:
if I had the table

| NAME | COMMENT |
| --- | --- |
| Jean | "This website seems a bit outdated for me" |
| Dela | "I didnt like it" |
| Nate | NA |
| Josh | "Very outdated" |

then I will be expecting something like this:

| NAME | CATEGORY |
| --- | --- |
| Jean | OUTDATED |
| Dela | "I didnt like it" |
| Nate | NO_COMMENT |
| Josh | OUTDATED |

Is there a library and documentation to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `grepl()` with `tolower()` function inside a nested `ifelse()`,

```
df$COMMENT <- ifelse(grepl('outdated',tolower(df$COMMENT)),'OUTDATED',
                ifelse(is.na(df$COMMENT),'NO_COMMENT',df$COMMENT))
```

*EDIT:*

Thanks to the comment of @RuiBarradas,

You can just use `grepl()` without `tolower()` by adding `TRUE` argument inside it as well,

```
df$COMMENT <- ifelse(grepl('outdated',df$COMMENT,TRUE),'OUTDATED',
                ifelse(is.na(df$COMMENT),'NO_COMMENT',df$COMMENT))
```

gives,

```
  NAME         COMMENT
1 Jean        OUTDATED
2 Dela I didnt like it
3 Nate      NO_COMMENT
4 Josh        OUTDATED
```

**Data:**

```
df <- data.frame(NAME=c("Jean","Dela","Nate","Josh"),
    COMMENT=c("This website seems a bit outdated for me",
        "I didnt like it",
        NA,
        "Very outdated"),stringsAsFactors=F)
```

Comment: Upvote but `grep` and `grepl` have a `ignore.case` argument (that defaults to `FALSE`), there's no need for the extra function call `tolower`.

Comment: @RuiBarradas Hmm.. I didn't know that argument. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

tidyverse pipe syntax

- `dplyr::case_when` helps passing multiple conditions for mutating a column
- `stringr::str_detect` gives TRUE or FALSE if given pattern is found inside the string passed.
- `tolower` eliminates the possibility of inclusion of `outdated` words in column in any case (upper, lower or mixed)

```
library(stringr)
library(dplyr)

df %>% mutate(COMMENT = case_when(str_detect(tolower(COMMENT), "outdated") ~ "OUTDATED",
                                  is.na(COMMENT) | COMMENT == "" ~ "NO_COMMENTS",
                                  TRUE ~ COMMENT))

  NAME         COMMENT
1 Jean        OUTDATED
2 Dela I didnt like it
3 Nate     NO_COMMENTS
4 Josh        OUTDATED
```

data used

```
df <- structure(list(NAME = c("Jean", "Dela", "Nate", "Josh"), COMMENT = c("This website seems a bit OUTDATED for me", 
"I didnt like it", NA, "Very Outdated")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-4L))

  NAME                                  COMMENT
1 Jean This website seems a bit OUTDATED for me
2 Dela                          I didnt like it
3 Nate                                     <NA>
4 Josh                            Very Outdated
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this, where `(?i)`ensures that the match will be case-**i**nsensitive:

```
df$COMMENT <- ifelse(grepl("(?i)outdated",df$COMMENT), "OUTDATED",
                     ifelse(is.na(df$COMMENT), "NO COMMENT", df$COMMENT))
```

Result:

```
df
  NAME         COMMENT
1 Jean        OUTDATED
2 Dela I didnt like it
3 Nate      NO COMMENT
4 Josh        OUTDATED
```